# EF4 Include not returning any of the navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I am using this

```
  public IQueryable<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Documents.Include("Company").Include("PostingStatus").Include("DocumentType").Include("Period");
    }
```

in my domainservice but its not returning anything to the client i am using WCF RIA Services and EF4 and Silverlight.

Does this have anything to do with some changes in EF4 regarding inner and outer joins it used to work in previous version of EF but dont know whats going on wrong.
Can you throw some light on this.

Thanks,
Aashish Gupta

Comment: It might help if you show your model (maybe screenshot the EDMX designer). I'm using EF4 in a current project and associations using Include is working fine.

Comment: Here is the link to edmx file http://www.smallworkarounds.com/tempfiles/edmx.png i think the entities which dont have relation are causing problem though they are not being used in the query which i am doing

Comment: I have tried removing the non related entities as well which were not having any relation with other entities but still i face the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my WCF RIA Services and EF4, which was fixed by manually adding the `[Include]` attribute to the appropriate navigation properties within the generated "*DomainService.metadata.cs" file.

See also:  http://xamlgeek.net/2010/02/21/include-related-properties-in-wcf-ria-services/

On the downside, this attribute gets blown away when regenerating the DomainService files.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the file and tried everything but it doesn't seem to work when on the client i externally specify like this

```
  (documentDomainDataSource.DomainContext as DocumentContext).AddReference(typeof(Company), company_ctx);
        (documentDomainDataSource.DomainContext as DocumentContext).AddReference(typeof(DocumentType), documentType_ctx);
        (documentDomainDataSource.DomainContext as DocumentContext).AddReference(typeof(Period), periods_ctx);
```

then it works but this is not the solution for which i am using Entity Framework and ria services.